# Can I use a for loop to build a JsonObject with Json.createObjectBuilder?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a new JsonObject with some values from different existing JsonObjects. I want to store the names of the values in for example a separate file, string...

```
JsonObject object1 = ...;
JsonObject object2 = ...;
String [] names1 = { ... };
String [] names2 = { ... };

JsonObject newObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add(names1[0], object1.getString(names1[0]))
.add(names1[1], object1.getString(names1[1]))
...
.add(names2[0], object2.getString(names2[0]))
.add(names2[1], object2.getString(names2[1]))
...
.build();
```

Can I instead add the names and values to the newObject using two foreach loops? This would allow me to change the names and fields that have to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, just keep the `JsonObjectBuilder` object:

```
JsonObject object1 = ...;
JsonObject object2 = ...;
String [] names1 = { ... };
String [] names2 = { ... };

JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
for(String name: names1)
  builder.add(name, object1.getString(name));
for(String name: names2)
  builder.add(name, object2.getString(name));
JsonObject newObject = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can iterate `names1` and `names2` variable's with two for loops and build the same logic you did here.

Comment: How do you iterate in the builder pattern?